# How can I color a PrefixLabel in Unity Editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, customization, unity3d-editor, unity-editor

My question is that simple: I just want to be able to use [`EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel.html) but change the text color to white.

But so far I have no luck.
I can easely change the color of all other elements but for the `PrefixLabel` nothing is working.
I want to stick with `PrefixLabel` since it simply is less code to have all labels and fields arranged well.

A fiew things I tried so far:

using [`EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyleState-textColor.html)

```c#
var old = EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor;
EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.white;
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("label Text");
EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = old;
```

additionally applying `new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.label)`

```c#
var old = EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor;
EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.white;
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("label Text", new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.label));
EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = old;
```

directly using [`EditorStyles.whiteLabel`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorStyles-whiteLabel.html)

```c#
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("label Text", new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.whiteLabel));
```

using [`GUI.contentColor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-contentColor.html)

```c#
var old = GUI.contentColor;
EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.white;
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("label Text");
GUI.contentColor = old;
```

using `GUI.skin.label.normal.textColor`

```c#
var old = GUI.skin.label.normal.textColor;
GUI.skin.label.normal.textColor = Color.white;
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("label Text");
GUI.skin.label.normal.textColor = old;
```

using a [`new GUIStyle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle.html)

```c#
whiteTextStyle = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.label) 
{ 
    normal = { 
        textColor = Color.white;
    } 
};
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("label Text", whiteTextStyle);
```

**Any hint what else I can try?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor` would already have worked but I had to reset the color back **after** the `EditorGUILayout.XYField` because the PrefixLabel was not drawed until the field call.

```c#
var old = EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor;
EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.white;
EditorGUILayout.PrefixLabel("label Text");

EditorGUILayout.IntField(5);

EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = old;
```