# Unity editor - How to stop field from turning blue when its edited

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I am making a tool in Unity to build your project for muliple platforms when you press a button.

I started with the preferences window for the tool, and came up with an anoying thing. Whenever I change the enum value of the EnumPopup field, the field turns blue in the editor window. Is there a way to disable this?

[image: This is the code I am using to show the enum field on the window]

[image: This is the window when the enum field has not been changed]

[image: This is the window when the enum field has been changed]

See how in the 2nd picture the field is not blue, and in the 3rd picture the field has changed to blue? How do I prevent this from happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't post code as Image but rather as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to help without having the rest of your code.

This is Unity built-in behaviour. I tried a lot of stuff [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51397298/7111561) to disable / overwrite the built-in coloring of prefix labels but had no luck so far.

---

A workarround however might be to instead use an independent [`EditorGUI.LabelField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.LabelField.html) which will not be affected by the `EnumPopup` together with the [`EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility-labelWidth.html):

```c#
var LabelRect = new Rect(
    FILEMANAGEMENT_ENUMFIELD_RECT.x, 
    FILEMANAGEMENT_ENUMFIELD_RECT.y,
    // use the current label width
    EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, 
    FILEMANAGEMENT_ENUMFIELD_RECT.height
);

var EnumRect = new Rect(
    FILEMANAGEMENT_ENUMFIELD_RECT.x + EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, 
    FILEMANAGEMENT_ENUMFIELD_RECT.y, 
    FILEMANAGEMENT_ENUMFIELD_RECT.width - EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth, 
    FILEMANAGEMENT_ENUMFIELD_RECT.height
);

EditorGUI.LabelField(LabelRect, "File relative to");
QuickBuilder.Settings.Relation = (QuickBuilder.Settings.PathRelation)EditorGUI.EnumPopup(EnumRect, QuickBuilder.Settings.Relation);
```

---

As you can see the label is not turned blue while the width keeps being flexible

[image]

---

**Sidenotes**
Instead of setting values via edito scripts directly like
`QuickBuilder.Settings.Relation =` you should always try and use the proper [SerializedProperty](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedProperty.html). It handles things like Undo/Redo and also marks the according objects and scenes as `dirty`.

Is there also a special reason why you use `EditorGUI` instead of `EditorGUILayout`? In the latter you don't need to setup `Rect`s.

```c#
EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
{
    EditorGUILayout.LabelField("File relative to", GUILayout.Width(EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth));
    QuickBuilder.Settings.Relation = (QuickBuilder.Settings.PathRelation)EditorGUILayout.EnumPopup(QuickBuilder.Settings.Relation);
}
EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at that !!

And yes I should implement serialized properties, but I just wanted to get something on screen, will change that in the future :D